# How can I make structs in an array mutable?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, jsondecoder

I have been using `JSONDecoder()` to decode a JSON into an array of structs.

```
import Foundation

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

func load (filename: String) -> Data {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
        return data
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }
}

func decode<T: Decodable> (data: Data) -> T {
    do {
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse input as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
} 

var ConditionsList: [ConditionInfo] = decode(data: load(filename: "TestJSON.json"))
```

`ConditionInfo` is a struct...

```
struct ConditionInfo: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let bulletList, paragraph, imageName, category, conditionName: String
    var isSaved: Bool
```

... for decoding a JSON that is an array of objects like this:

```
   {
      "conditionName": "condition1",
      "id": 0,
      "category": "CategoryA",
      "isSaved": false,
      "bulletList": "- Test Text 1\n - Test Text 1\n - Test Text 1\n",
      "paragraph": "Assumenda soluta voluptatem accusantium consequuntur. Corporis magni nulla eos impedit quia eum. Quo omnis quisquam explicabo qui ducimus inventore. Qui dolorem odit deserunt minima ut impedit totam. Aperiam quae molestiae reiciendis hic.",
      "imageName": "turtlerock"
   }
```

However later in my code I try to loop through `ConditionsList` and mutate instances of `ConditionInfo`...

```
var currentIdChecking = 0
for (loopN, loopConditionInfo) in ConditionsList.enumerated() {
      if loopConditionInfo.conditionName == savedConditionsStatus[currentIdChecking].conditionName {
      loopConditionInfo.isSaved = savedConditionsStatus[currentIdChecking].isSaved
      currentIdChecking += 1
    }
}
```

I get the error `Cannot assign to property: 'loopConditionInfo' is a 'let' constant` on the `loopConditionInfo.isSaved =` section of code.  (`SavedConditionsStatus` is a array very similar to `ConditionsList` except it has slightly different variables in its struct.  This loop is just trying to copy some data from it.). I have searched online and everything I have seen has talked about making sure that I declare variables and not constants in the struct.  However, I am trying to edit `.isSaved` which is a variable in `ConditionInfo`.  Additionally, `ConditionsList` is also a variable, so I do not understand where the troublesome let constant is.  How do I fix this so that I can edit instances of `ConditionInfo` in the `ConditionsList` array?

Comment: You need to enumerate your array indices and use them to mutate the array elements

Comment: probably something like `for index in ConditionsList.indices {`
      `if ConditionsList[index].conditionName == savedConditionsStatus[currentIdChecking].conditionName {`
     `ConditionsList[index].isSaved = savedConditionsStatus[currentIdChecking].isSaved`
      `currentIdChecking += 1`
   `}`
`}`